# Ошибка работы с AssyncTask

Tags: android

Приложение выпадает с таким страшным логом:

```
09-22 10:22:31.920    9798-9823/com.musictext.denis.musictext E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:854)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4075)
            at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10386)
            at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:8488)
            at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:5716)
            at **com.musictext.denis.musictext.fragment.ForeignArtistFragment$1.onSend(ForeignArtistFragment.java:77)
            at com.musictext.denis.musictext.object.SendParamToUrl.doInBackground(SendParamToUrl.java:31)
            at com.musictext.denis.musictext.object.SendParamToUrl.doInBackground(SendParamToUrl.java:21)**
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

У меня есть два фрагмента. Которые одновременно подключаются к серверу и получают данные. Ниже код где идет отправка.

```
SendParamToUrl sendParamToUrl = new SendParamToUrl("http://music.kamnedsoft.kz/api/get_artist");
        sendParamToUrl.callBackSendDate = sendDateCallBack;
        sendParamToUrl.execute(ListParam);
```

Класс SendParamToUrl отвечает за отправку данных на сервер.

```
public class SendParamToUrl  extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<SendParam>, String, String> {
    String URL;

    public SendParamToUrl(String URL) {
        this.URL = URL;
    }
    public CallBackSendDate callBackSendDate;
    protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<SendParam>... params)
    {
        String response=" ";
        callBackSendDate.onSend("Идет загрузка...");
        try
        {
            DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
            //String URL = "http://music.kamnedsoft.kz/api/get_category";
            //он у нас будет посылать post запрос
            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(URL);
            //будем передавать два параметра
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(params[0].size());

            //передаем параметры из наших текстбоксов
            for(SendParam info : params[0])
            {
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(info.name, info.value));
            }

            //собераем их вместе и посылаем на сервер
            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));

            //получаем ответ от сервера
            response = hc.execute(postMethod, res);
            return response.toString();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("myTag", String.valueOf(e));
            callBackSendDate.onError("Сервер не доступен");
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        callBackSendDate.onSend("");
        callBackSendDate.onReturnAnswer(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

Если отключать один из фрагментов данные спокойно получают от сервера. Если одновременно два то выпадает ошибка с выше логом.

В чем может быть проблема? вроде создаются разные ссылки на класс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что вы пытаетесь дергать разметку из не основного (UI) потока.

Судя по всему проблема в вызове метода `callBackSendDate.onSend("Идет загрузка...");` в `doInBackground`.

Если вы в нём пытаетесь показывать факт запуска процесса, по делать это надо в методе `onPreExecute`. Т.е. вам надо переместить `callBackSendDate.onSend("Идет загрузка...");` в `onPreExecute`.

Comment: Спасибо помогло, только вот не могу понять, почему с одним фрагментом работает, и не выдает никакую ошибку, а с двумя обваливается?

Comment: А хрен его знает... Это надо глубоко копать, чтоб понять... При нынешнем наборе условий предположений сделать никаких не могу.

Comment: )) TY! Юрий а можно вопрос? как обратиться к меню которое создано activity Из фрагментов, и отлавливвать событие?

Comment: Тут посмотрите: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24526941/3212712